# Convert .ttf to .bdf

Tags: fonts, truetype

How do I convert a monospace True Type font to a BDF font with 14x28 (or 14x30) characters?

My first thought was to use FontForge, but for some reason, when I open a True Type font:

- if I try to "Generate Fonts", it won't let me select any bitmap font formats, and
- there is no "export" option under the "file" menu
  ([they claim otherwise](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/filemenu.html)), and
- if I "save as" and change the file extension, I don't get a BDF font ... just a TTF font with a BDF extension.

I am using FontForge version: 23:48 GMT 23-Sep-2009 which I retrieved from the OpenSUSE repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [ttf2bdf](http://sbiswas.tripod.com/ttf2bdf/) It looks like it's in the ["freetype-tools"](http://pkgs.org/opensuse-11.2/opensuse-oss-x86_64/freetype-tools-1.3.1-1393.1.x86_64.rpm.html) package for SuSE. Not sure which version you're running. It might be worth giving a shot. If fontforge will let you open an existing .bdf, you might be able to resize it after conversion.

Comment: It seems that ttf2bdf has now been superseded by [otf2bdf](http://sofia.nmsu.edu/~mleisher/Software/otf2bdf/), which claims to have bug fixes and to use the Freetype 2 library shipped with current (2022) distributions.